# Jlist not displaying my items in String

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, runtime-error, jlist

```
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("add");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Main selectedValue = (Main)courseList.getSelectedValue();
            if(selectedValue !=null){
                orderList.addElement(chosenList);
        }
        }
    });
```

i have created a addButton which adds elements from one `Jlist` to another `Jlist`. However, when i run my applction and click the add buttton it gives me this error in my chosenList `Jlist`:

> javax.swing.JList[,-2008,0,2255x182,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=50332008,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,fixedCellHeight=-1,fixedCellWidth=-1,horizontalScrollIncrement=-1,selectionBackground=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],selectionForeground=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],visibleRowCount=8,layoutOrientation=0]

Comment: It looks like you're adding an entire `JList` as a single element. Loop over the items in it, and add each one individually.

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `orderList.add(selectedValue);` ?

Comment: i changed it to 'orderList.add(selectedValue);' but this is also wrong ass the addElement is red and say this 'addElement(JList) in the type DefaultListModel<JList> is not applicable for the arguments (Main)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `addElement` method should be called on an instance of class `DefaultListModel`.

If you previously has added a `DefaultListModel` instance as the model for your `orderList`, you should use following code to add the element to your `orderList`.

```
Object selectedValue = courseList.getSelectedValue();
DefaultListModle listModel = (DefaultListModle)orderList.getModel();
listModel.addElement(selectedValue);
```

If you haven't set any instance of class which implements `ListModel`, you should initialize your `orderList` in this way:

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
orderList = new JList(listModel);
// or
orderList.setModel(listModel);
```

Take a look at [How to Use Lists from Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: the `orderList.getModel();` is wrong also its saying this The method getModel() is undefined for the type DefaultListModel<JList>

Comment: @mikeb So now I see that your `orderList` is of type `DefaultListModel` rather than `JList`. You need to post more code to let us see what's going on in your code. If `orderList` is a `DefaultListModel`, then you should be able to add the element using `orderList.addElement(selectedValue)`. Two things, naming your variables properly like changing `orderList` to `orderListModel`, and show me what `Main` is.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in your list is not an error, but the `toString()` value for your `chosenList` object. Perhaps you mean to do the following instead:

```
orderList.addElement(selectedValue);
```

Instead of:

```
orderList.addElement(chosenList);
```

Comment: i have done the change but this just gives me another error saying this : The method addElement(JList) in the type DefaultListModel<JList> is not applicable for the arguments (Main)